# emissive effect on obj in three.js using obj and mtl loaders

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to achieve the glowing / emissive effect scene below on my obj of pants:

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v2i5.png)

Here is my code at the moment:

```
        //pant map and obj

    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( 'Ftest2/' );
    mtlLoader.setPath( 'Ftest2/' );
    mtlLoader.load( 'jean1.mtl', function( materials ) {


    materials.preload();


    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'Ftest2/' );
    objLoader.load( 'jean1.obj', function ( object ) {

        object.position.y = -24;
        pants = object; 
        pants.visible = true; 
        scene.add( pants );

        }, onProgress, onError );

        });
```

On that same note, how can I apply other interesting effects (like showing the wireframe, applying a glass look, etc. using the above code)?

Please note that I need to use the mtl loader, and cannot map directly on the .obj on this project.

Comment: I was able to use just .obj's and textures, without .mtls. I have been experimenting with Phong and emissive properties, but haven't gotten the right effect, anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Using MeshBasicMaterial gave me the desired effect instead of phong or lambert.